# Nginx path proxy pass to backend server ASP net cannot load certain CSS and JS files

Tags: asp.net, nginx, proxypass

I am using Nginx as a Web Proxy to my backend web server which is running ASP.NET 4.5.

The ASP server serves HTML page dynamically and it is managed by another developer.

The `script` section of the main web html shows:

```
<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>
<link href="/Content/css?v=0CO7wbdAKgh6VVE0St8oKqJBcB4RpFIbcQS63jv2JjY1" rel="stylesheet"/>
...
...
<script src="/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bundles/WebFormsJs?v=AAyiAYwMfvmwjNSBfIMrBAqfU5exDukMVhrRuZ-PDU01" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Please notice the inconsistency of backward slash `/` in the above code.**

Here is my Nginx proxy configuration:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://SOME_CMS_WORDPRESS_SERVER;
    }

    location /aspsite/ {
        proxy_pass http://ASP_NET_SERVER_IP/;
    }
```

When I tried to access the URL (e.g. `http://example.com/aspsite/`) the webpage shows missing CSS files and some JS files from the `bundles` folder on the ASP.NET web server.

However the `Scripts` files are all loaded.

My ASP.NET developer told me that he doesn't know how to change the backward slash as he is using a template to dynamically generate those `src=xxxx` lines.

My question is:

Is it possible to get all the CSS and JS files via nginx proxy in this case?

Do I need to change ASP.NET code? How?

Do I need to add some rewrite rules to Nginx? How?